# Match line break at end of line

Tags: regex, scala

```
scala> "foo\nbar".replaceAll("\n[^\n]+$", "#")
val res78: String = foo# // <- GOOD
```

```
scala> "foo\nbar\n".replaceAll("\n[^\n]+$", "#")
val res77: String = "foo# // <- ????
"
```

Why does it strip the second line here, ending with "\n" (but not the line break itself)???
I figure, it "consumes" `\n` into `$` ... But how do I make it NOT do this?

Comment: It seems like scala's `replaceAll` interprets regex as with multiline flag enabled, and `$` is not only end of string, but also end of line too. To avoid it you can use `\\z` instead.

Comment: If you're specifically tring to find the last line: Multi-line mode `\r?\n[^\r\n]+\s*\z`, no multi-line `\r?\n[^\r\n]+\s*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `replaceAll` works with implicit global and multiline flags. As a result, `$` stands not only for end of the string, but also end of the line.

See this two demos of matching `$` with `m` flag opted in: [your example](https://regex101.com/r/Fpl0MX/1) and [more general one](https://regex101.com/r/ReIvD9/1). Hope this clarifies what happened.

To avoid this behavior you can use `\z` anchor. It assert end of the string regardless of flags being used.

Demo of matches with `\z`: [with trailing newline](https://regex101.com/r/gzsS9n/1), [without trailing newline](https://regex101.com/r/4DWT6Z/1)

Demo of the code with both approaches [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ASB3bu9QQ2eeigtjis6uPA).